# (Rails) How do I mimic Finder/Explorer views with contextual menus, etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface, treeview, explorer, finder

I'm looking for some quality techniques for mimicking a Finder (or "Explorer View").  Eventually I want to have treeviews, contextual menus, etc.  I'm guessing there is going to be a good deal of Javascript, which is fine, I'm just curious as to whether there are quality existing helpers, etc for any of these things.

The current relationship model is as follows:

```
   Sites -> Buildings -> Meters -> Values
```

There is a polymorphic relationship with Charts, so there's also:

```
   Sites -> Charts
   Buildings -> Charts
   Meters -> Charts
```

I already have the add/remove logic for most of the items, I simply want to improve the GUI.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ExtJS library.
Here is an example: http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/column-tree.html

Update:
Here's a working link: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/tree

Comment: Thanks, but not interested in commercial items right now.  I appreciate the post though.